# State on my component wont update when passing new props

Tags: reactjs, class, components

I have a component which i use props value passed by the parent component to update the state (forms component) . I have another component (list component) which changes the value of the state of a parent component which will effectively change the value of the props that is passed to the forms component. however, the state in my forms component wont update. here is my code on the forms component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';


class Form extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
       
        this.state = {
            name: this.props.name || '',
            id: this.props.id || '',
            complete: this.props.complete || false,
            edit: this.props.edit || false,
        }

    }

   


    handleChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value,
            edit: false, 
            complete: false, 
            id: uuidv4(),
            
        })
        


    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
       
        this.props.addListing(this.state.name, this.state.id, this.state.edit, this.state.complete)

        this.setState({
            name: '',
            id: ''
        })
        
    }

  
   componentDidUpdate() {
         console.log('for editing', this.state)
   }




    render () {
        
        return (
            <div>
                <form 
                onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                
                action="">
                    <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="search" name="name" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.name} placeholder="Enter Property Name" />
                    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
                    <button type='reset' >Reset</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Form;
```

here is the my parent component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import './App.css'
import Header from './components/Header'
import Form from './components/Form'
import List from './components/List'


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      properties: localStorage.getItem('properties') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('properties')) : [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      edit: false,
      complete: false
    }
  }





  addListing = (name, id, edit, complete) => {
    this.setState({
      properties: [...this.state.properties, {name, id, edit, complete}],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      edit: false,
      complete: false

    })
    
  }

  forEdit = (id) => {

    const newProperties = this.state.properties.map(property => {
      if (property.id === id) {
        this.setState ({
          name: property.name,
          id: property.id,
          edit: property.edit,
          complete: property.complete
          
        })
        console.log('for edit', property)
      }
      return property
    })
    this.setState({
      properties: newProperties
    })
    

  }


  render() {
    
    localStorage.setItem('properties', JSON.stringify(this.state.properties))

    
    return (
      <div> 
          <Header />  
          
          <Form 
            addListing={this.addListing}
            name = {this.state.name}
            id = {this.state.id}
            edit = {this.state.edit}
            complete = {this.state.complete}



          
          />
          <List 
            properties={this.state.properties}
            forEdit = {this.forEdit}
          
          />
      </div>
      


    )
  }
}


export default App
```

i try to run the console log for both props and state. the props is correct, but the state wont change. i need the state to change in order for the name variable to appear in my input box.

Comment: Don't create a state out of the props you are getting from the outside. This is really bad React. If you need to, pass functions from `App` to update the state of the `App` in `Form`. And in `Form`, only read the props, don't try to mutate them.